# Convert private key to integer

Tags: private-key, private-key-format

I have a random private key (compressed or uncompressed) `5HpHagT65TZzG1QDbnQCzdudnpknN7nA1SLEt4ZcxsH2SV92yqt` or `KwDiBf89QgGbjEmUcXPRwPuKPFnFECvJkvovGNiyjaujMCrQXy98`. How do I convert this private key back to an integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the key is the posted  compressed WIF `KwDiBf89QgGbjEmUcXPRwPuKPFnFECvJkvovGNiyjaujMCrQXy98`:

1. Decode the key you have using the encoder used (in this case [base-58](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding))
   `80-00000000000000000006f5d7d806edef2e1110b0b243f9a90c2aaaaaaaaaaaaa-01-098dbf37`
2. Remove the [extra bytes](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format) (version byte, compressed byte if present, checksum)
   `00000000000000000006f5d7d806edef2e1110b0b243f9a90c2aaaaaaaaaaaaa`
3. Take the remaining bytes (in this case it must be 32 bytes) and convert it to an integer assuming it is positive and in [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) (most significant value is stored first).
   `666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666`

Comment: @The Gripmaster you should also add that entering "private key" in a website is not a good idea.